# Why is assignment not allowed in if statement in Python

Tags: python

Why is assignment not allowed in `if` statements in Python ?
In other languages like c it is possible to use this code.

#### code Python:

```
>>> if x=12:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### code C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
if (int x=1)
{
    cout<<"ok";
    }
}
```

in `for`/`while` statement is the same:

```
>>> while (x=input())!='q':

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It's way too error-prone and adds extremely little expressive power.

Comment: It's just a language design decision, this was perceived to be the source of bugs in other languages so python doesn't allow it.

Comment: I see this pep asking for something similar , but it was withdrawn - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0379/

Comment: because Python is not C++?

Comment: See: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression.htm

Answer (score 4):

It's true. For better and worse, Python distinguishes strictly between expressions and statements, and the latter don't have values. In particular, assignment statements don't have values, and so can't be used in conditionals.

Answer (score -4):

Remember for Python to use two equals signs.

```
if x == 12
   *Enter expressions here*
```

Comment: Unfortunately this misses the point of the question, the asker of this question is aware of the Python syntax here.

Comment: Both C && C++ use '==' for equality, and clearly OP understands the distinction between that and '='.

Comment: This is not the correct explanation of the question asked

Comment: You should remove this answer. It serves no purpose. Removing it can at least get you a 'Peer Pressure' badge.